# IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a django view that causes FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. This is coming from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613272/foreign-key-constraint-failed-on-django-model-instance?noredirect=1#comment119522907_67613272)

```
def return_book(request,pk):
    books = Books.objects.filter(school = request.user.school).get(id = pk)
    book = Issue.objects.get(book_id_id=pk,book_id__school_id = request.user.school.id)
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    Return.objects.create(borrowed_item_id=book.id,returner=user)
    Books.Addbook(books) 
    Issue.objects.get(book_id_id=pk).delete()
    return redirect("view_books")
```

The erro is returned at `Issue.objects.get(book_id_id=pk).delete()`
I don't know the exact cause of this error. Could somebody explain to me what's going on hat causes the error>
The Traceback is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Django\test projects\library manage\lib_system\Library-System\libman\views.py", line 209, in return_book
    Issue.objects.get(book_id_id=pk).delete()#Borrower_id is also required in the filter
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 947, in delete
    return collector.delete()
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 396, in delete
    count = sql.DeleteQuery(model).delete_batch([instance.pk], self.using)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 43, in delete_batch
    num_deleted += self.do_query(self.get_meta().db_table, self.where, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 23, in do_query
    cursor = self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    borrower_id = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    issuer = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Return(models.Model):
    return_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    borrowed_item = models.ForeignKey(Issue,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    returner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models, this is due to an `on_delete=...` of a `ForeignKey`, likely you have set this to `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`.

Comment: Added the models. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: well `DO_NOTHING` is typically *not* a good option since (most) databases will now see that `borrowed_item` refers to an `Issue` that no longer exists, hence the error. Usually one either removes all the `Return` objects with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, or you make the field NULLable, and set it to `NULL`/`None`.

Comment: Actually I'm struggling to create a history of all ever borrowed items by a particular student. So, all this you explain will mean this is not possible here?????

Comment: the problem is that now your `Return` refers to an `Issue` that is removed. If you want to keep a history, you might want to implement a "soft delete" for the issue that has a boolean that specifies if the item is removed or not. If it is removed (the field is `True`), we do not show this in the list of available items.

Comment: You've introduced a new thing, the soft-delete. How will it do here?????

Comment: it adds two extra fields to the model `is_deleted` and `deleted_at` that will keep track if  an object is supposed to be deleted. In reality it is still in the database, but the `is_deleted` is set to `True`, and there is filtering to only retrieve items that have `is_deleted` set to `False`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55900209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `DO_NOTHING` is typically *not* a good option since (most) databases will check *referential integrity*. This means that they guarantee that if a `ForeignKey` refers (in this case to an `Issue`), then that means that the table that stores the issues should have a record with the primary key the `Return` item refers to.

Often `DO_NOTHING` is used in combination with a certain trigger in the database system (that Django is not aware of).

Typically the most popular choices for`on_delete` are:

1. `models.CASCADE`: in that case it will remove all `Return`s related to the removed item;
2. `models.PROTECT`: in that case it will raise an error to prevent removing the `Issue`; and
3. `models.SET_NULL`: this is done on a `NULL`able field (so with `null=Ture`), in which case the impacted `Return`(s) will set the field to `NULL`/`None`.

Another option might be to "soft delete" records, for example with the [**`django-soft-delete`** package [pypi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-soft-delete/). In that case a boolean is added to the `Issue` that specifies if the item is removed. The package will also transparently filter the objects, such that you only retrieve records that are "alive".

Answer (score 1):

*This edge case is not directly relevant for the OP, but may help others that wind up here based on the title:*

An `IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` will also be raised when trying to `delete` some object `x`, if there is a table in your database that Django is unaware of, and this table has a reference to object `x`.

This can happen, for example, if you remove a model from your code without properly migrating the changes.

As a result, the table remains in the database, but Django does not know anything about it, so, when object `x` is deleted, Django does not know it should also delete the corresponding row from this "orphaned" table.